# How do I target a specific Mac OS X version?

Tags: c, macos, version

If I want to target all iOS devices version 4.3 or later, I can use:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_4_3
```

Also, if I want to target iOS devices in general, I can use:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
```

Is there something similar for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSAppKitVersionNumber` is your friend on OS X. To target eg. 10.5 and upwards, you can do this:

```
#if NSAppKitVersionNumber >= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5

// ...

#endif
```

**Edit:** Just seen that there are also `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` and `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` on OS X, which might work better and which are available in the `Availability.h` which is not Cocoa dependent.

Comment: Nice, and if I'm not on Mac OS X (for example, if I am on iOS), then `NSAppKitVersionNumber` will not be defined, right? This way, I could tell I'm on Mac OS X in general, by checking if this is defined?

Comment: @Radu Yup. `NSAppKitVersionNumber` is defined only on OS X (or better say its defined in Cocoa. If you don't use Cocoa, you can revert to `Gestalt` and weak-linking (which works (afair!) on 10.6.8 and upwards)

Comment: @Radu Look into `/usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h`, they start with two underscores. And yes, possible values to along are similar to iOS: `__MAC_10_0`, `__MAC_10_7` etc (look into `/usr/include/Availability.h`